# Using a Skewed Associative Cache in Gem5

Tags: gem5

I am trying to learn how to implement an L2 cache with a skewed associativity.
I see there is already implemented classes for skewed associativity (skewed_associative.cc/hh) under
/gem5/src/mem/cache/tags/indexing_policies/
and i would like to use this to start off with.

What I do not understand is how to access those files and specify a given cache to act as a skewed associative. Do I need to create an entire new cache class that inherits from the basecache? Or is there a way to do it through implementing a new tag?

I'm still trying to figure out how gem5 has anything structured/works, so any amount of help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked "learning gem5" (http://learning.gem5.org/book/)? You will need to set up your system with the configuration that you want, and then, when instantiating your cache, assigning its tags' indexing_policy as SkewedAssociative(). Something along the lines of system.l2 = MyCache(tags=BaseSetAssoc(indexing_policy=SkewedAssociative()))

Comment: You can check configs/CacheConfig.py for an example of cache instantiation in a system. Instead of having "system.l2 = l2_cache_class(clk_domain=system.cpu_clk_domain, **_get_cache_opts('l2', options))", you'd have "system.l2 = l2_cache_class(clk_domain=system.cpu_clk_domain, tags=BaseSetAssoc(indexing_policy=SkewedAssociative()), **_get_cache_opts('l2', options))"

Comment: okay great. thanks a ton! this helps point me in the right direction for now.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho Thank you for the help. I was able to add the above and it worked perfectly.
I am still slightly confused on how adding it there was the correct location. I went through and read the learning gem5 - adding a new simobject, since that was the part that seemed relevant, and it was unclear as to why the above solution was the way to go? is there a better exampled that I am missing? 
again, thanks a ton!

Comment: It worked because you are probably using configs/example/se.py (or fs.py) to run your simulations of the Classic memory. These files have a call to setup the cache with the configuration file mentioned above (in se.py, search for "CacheConfig.config_cache(options, system)"). These are basic files that are provided as is, so at some point in the future you may need to create your own system configuration files. You are highly encouraged to create your own set of configuration files to avoid relying on configurations that may change (e.g., an update to them may change your results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comments helped lead to a solution.

When instantiating a given cache, assign its tags' indexing_policy as SkewedAssociative()

in configs/common/CacheConfig.py:

Instead of having:

```
system.l2 = l2_cache_class(clk_domain=system.cpu_clk_domain, **_get_cache_opts('l2', options))
```

you'd have

```
system.l2 = l2_cache_class(clk_domain=system.cpu_clk_domain, tags=BaseSetAssoc(indexing_policy=SkewedAssociative()), **_get_cache_opts('l2', options))
```